# Why does construction of optimization last too long using CVXPY?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, cvxpy

I have set up a simple linear MPC problem using python's CVXPY. The optimization problem is solved with the ECOS solver and is pretty fast. The problem is that the formulation of the optimization problem, i.e., the construction of the objective function and the constraints, takes too much time. Indicatively, I have attached a picture, where the time needed to construct the optimization problem is shown, for each time-step, along with the time needed to solve it (units are in seconds). I expected that the situation would be reversed, meaning that the procedure of solving the optimization would last longer than its construction. Is this happening because I am using CVXPY to formulate it and should I use another framework for setting up the problem ? I am running it on a MacBook Pro with intel i9 processor.

[image]

The lines of code defining the optimization code are given below with Np set equal to 20 and Nc equal to 3. A and B are constant matrices with dimensions `(2x2)` and `(2x1)`, respectively.

```
    Du = cp.Variable((M, Np)) 
    x = cp.Variable((W, Np+1))
    obj = 0
    constr = []
    ref = createZRefVector.createPredictionVector(k, Ts, Np)
    w_1 = 1.0
    w_2 = 0.01

    tic_con = time.perf_counter()
    for h in range(Np):

        obj += w_1*cp.power((x[0, h + 1] - ref[h]), 2.0) + 0.01 * cp.power(Du[:, h], 2.0) + w_2*cp.power((x[1, h + 1] + 0.1), 2.0)

        if h <= Nc:
            u = Du[:, h] + ftPrev
            ftPrev = u
            constr += [x[:, h + 1] == A @ x[:, h] + B @ u + G, cp.abs(Du[:, h]) <= 5.0, cp.abs(u) <= 30.0]
        else:
            u = Du[:, h] + ftPrev
            ftPrev = u
            constr += [x[:, h + 1] == A @ x[:, h] + B @ u + G, cp.abs(Du[:, h]) <= 5.0, Du[:, h] == Du[:, Nc], cp.abs(u) <= 30.0]

    constr += [x[:, 0] == z0]
    problem = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(obj), constr)
    toc_con = time.perf_counter()
```

**EDIT:** I have also observed a huge difference in terms of the time needed to solve the optimization problem when comparing the stats returned by the solver `problem.solve(..)` and the corresponding measured time using Python's `tic-toc` placed right before and right after the line of code, where the solver is called. Does it have anything to do with Python and which one should I trust more ?

Comment: There is some expected overhead for all those internal DCP-framework based processings. Doing it more quickly without a framework as high-lvl as cvxpy is absolutely possible, but it's not that trivial and hard to do (e.g. abs linearization and what else is needed) quickly (sparse matrix ops which usually means dynamic memory-allocation) without going for a systems-programming language. It's also not that cvxpy is slow or bad: last time i checked the DCP framework was coded in C++ and the sparse-ops are at least based on scipy.sparse (but maybe dedicated c++?).  High-lvlness seems to hurt here

Comment: If you really want to solve lots of tiny problems at high frequency then a modelling tool + python make sense at the prototyping stage, after that you will want to use the solver API directly.  When we talk about problems small enough to solve at 0.003 sec. then the modeling time becomes a very significant component.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I suppose you mean that I should formulate the problem using directly the ECOS API (for example) functions and guidelines ? Another thing I would like to add is that I compared the 'timer' returned along with the solution of the problem against a tic toc python counter and there was huge difference. Python's tic-toc (time.perf_counter()) measured much more time need t execute the solve line of the code. Is that something to do with the Python interpreter ? Which one should I trust more ?

Comment: No it's not about the python interpreter. Look what you are measuring and read their code or docs what they are measuring. You are obviously comparing different timings. The only real clock-based caveat is wall- vs. cpu-time but both measurements will be based on wall-time.     In your example code shown you are clearly not measuring solve (and DCP) itself (solve is not shown) which probably means that you do something very different than whats being shown.